# An unauthenticated user can still see the "/account" page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

An unauthenticated user can still see the "/account" page for a few seconds I mean there is still a delay of a few seconds before the unauthenticated user is completely redirected to another page. even though I have used ProtectedRoute, how can I make unauthenticated users unable to see the "/account" page at all without delay? i use react-router-dom 6.6.1 and firebase auth

here is for the app.js

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate} from 'react-router-dom'
import Home from './components/Home'
import Account from './components/Account';
import Signin from './components/Home/Signin';
import theme from './theme';
import { AuthContextProvider } from './components/Context/AuthContext';
import ProtectedRoute from './components/ProtectedRoute';


function App() {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AuthContextProvider>
    <Router>
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
        <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
        <Route path='/account' element={<ProtectedRoute><Account /></ProtectedRoute>} />
      </Routes>
      </Router>
      </AuthContextProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    
  )
}

export default App
```

and this is for the ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { UserAuth } from './Context/AuthContext';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children }) => {
  const { user } = UserAuth();

  if (!user) {
    return <Navigate to='/' />;
  }
  return children;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

this if for the UserAuth :

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from 'firebase/auth';
import { auth } from '../../firebase';

const UserContext = createContext();

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});

  const createUser = (email, password) => {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  };

   const signIn = (email, password) =>  {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
   }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{ createUser, user, signIn }}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const UserAuth = () => {
  return useContext(UserContext);
};
```

I want to redirect unauthenticated users to the main page without delay

Comment: You'll need to show us the code for `UserAuth`.

Comment: Sorry, i've edited my post @emeraldsanto

Answer (score 0):

it’s probably due to the fact that your guard is validating off of `!user` however your initial auth state has user as `{}`. In this case an empty object will validate as truthy.

You could either set the initial state of user as `null` or you could update th guard validation to check for a value on `user` like `if (!user.id) …`

Comment: The `id` param was just generic. I’m not sure what firebase sets as a user object so you’d have to validate off that. Easiest might just be setting initial value to `null` if you’re not sure of the shape of the user object from firebase.

Answer (score 0):

Render Protected and Base routes conditional so unauthenticated user never have access of Protected routes.

Use the following code.
Always make separate file for routing for better code readability and Separation of concerns.

BaseRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

import Home from './components/Home'
import Signin from './components/Home/Signin';

const BaseRoutes = (
  <>
    <Route path='/' element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='/signin' element={<Signin />} />
  </>
)

export default BaseRoutes
```

ProtectedRoutes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom';

import Account from './components/Account';

const ProtectedRoutes = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Route path='/account' element={<Account />} />
    </>
  )
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Routes.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Navigate, Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { UserAuth } from './Context/AuthContext';

import ProtectedRoutes from './components/ProtectedRoutes';
import BaseRoutes from './components/BaseRoutes';

const Router = () => {

  const { user } = UserAuth();
  const isUser = Boolean(user)
  const redirectUrl = isUser ? '/account' : '/signin'

  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        {isUser ? <BaseRoutes /> : <ProtectedRoutes />}
        <Route
          path="*"
          element={<Navigate to={redirectUrl} />}
        />
      </Routes> 
    </BrowserRouter>  
  ) 
}

export default Router
```

app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AuthContextProvider } from './components/Context/AuthContext';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import theme from './theme';
import Router from './routes'

function App() {

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Router />
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default App
```